# Adding a stage column to my R data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to add a stage column to my R data frame. Using JMP, I would tackle this problem recursively with a column formula which I think would translate as something like:

```
mutate(group_by(df, experiment_id),
  stage = ifelse(row_number(setpoint) == 1, 1,
      ifelse(lead(setpoint, 1) != setpoint,
             lag(stage, 1) + 1,
             lag(stage, 1))))
```

However, this approach doesn't work with dplyr and there seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/925) with `lag` and `group_by`, so I'm wondering how I could write a function for dplyr which would increment stages for me:

```
mutate(example, stage = stage(setpoint1, setpoint2))
```

Here the `stage` function accepts from one to n continuous setpoint variables, which when any of them changes, increments the stage.  For example,

```
example <-
    data_frame(n=1:10,
               sp1=c(rep(3, 3), rep(5, 4), rep(8, 3)),
               sp2=c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(5, 5)))
mutate(example, stage = stage(sp1, sp2))
```

This should give:

```
|    |  n | sp1 | sp2 | stage |
|----+----+-----+-----+-------|
|  1 |  1 |   3 |   1 | 1     |
|  2 |  2 |   3 |   1 | 1     |
|  3 |  3 |   3 |   1 | 1     |
|  4 |  4 |   5 |   2 | 2     |
|  5 |  5 |   5 |   2 | 2     |
|  6 |  6 |   5 |   5 | 3     |
|  7 |  7 |   5 |   5 | 3     |
|  8 |  8 |   8 |   5 | 4     |
|  9 |  9 |   8 |   5 | 4     |
| 10 | 10 |   8 |   5 | 4     |
```

My data consists of experiments sampled periodically over the course of a few days, so the stages indices need to be sequential starting from 1.  `group_indices` seems to sort the data when assigning groups, and does it seem to catch all stages as can be seen by changing the example slightly:

```
> example <-
+     data_frame(n=1:10,
+                sp1=c(rep(8, 3), rep(3, 4), rep(8, 3)),
+                sp2=c(rep(3, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(1, 5)))
> example %>% mutate(stage = group_indices(., paste0(sp1, sp2)))
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]

    n sp1 sp2 stage
1   1   8   3     4
2   2   8   3     4
3   3   8   3     4
4   4   3   2     2
5   5   3   2     2
6   6   3   1     1
7   7   3   1     1
8   8   8   1     3
9   9   8   1     3
10 10   8   1     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

After discussion in chat we found the working solution to be:

```
example %>% 
  mutate(x = paste0(sp1, sp2), 
         stage = cumsum(x != c(0, head(x, -1)))) %>% 
  select(-x)
```

Comment: You don't need `paste` just `setDT(example)[, stage := .GRP, .(sp1, sp2)]` should do. Though I don't think this works on `data_frame` class...

Comment: I know, I was going to add a comment on data_frame/data.frame

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! However, my example was atypical for my data since the set points don't always increase. Please see the new example.

Comment: @wdkrnls, see my update. does that produce the desired output?

Comment: @docendodiscimus: your output looks right, but trying to reproduce it, my stage column just has NA. I just copied your code verbatim and pasted it into R.

Comment: @wdkrnls, did you try it with the example data from the question or your real data?

Comment: @docendodiscimus: The (second) example data from the question. I'm using dplyr 0.4.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71533/discussion-between-docendo-discimus-and-wdkrnls).